# Extra vertical space at end of last column when loading adjustbox (only luatex)

Tags: spacing, luatex, two-column, debugging, adjustbox

I have noticed some odd extra vertical when placing boxes in a twocolumn layout:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{calc}
% issue only happens with adjustbox loaded
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\parindent=0pt
\fboxrule=1pt
\fboxsep=5mm

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    \section*{sec1}
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{minipage}}

\vfill

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    \section*{sec2}
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{minipage}}

\vfill

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    \section*{sec3}
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{minipage}}

\vfill

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    \section*{sec4}
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Here are the outputs for `lualatex`

[image: lualatex output]

and `pdflatex`/`xelatex`

[image: pdflatex output]

As you can see, the `lualatex` version has some extra space at the bottom of the right column (it seems to be around 5pt). As the comment says, this only occurs with the `adjustbox` package loaded.

Is this a bug (and if so, where) and can I work around it?

*Using LuaTeX v1.0.4/TeX Live 2017.*

Comment: Issue report for adjustbox: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/issues/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not luatex specific. You get the same problem with pdflatex if you load pgf. pdf adds `\AtBeginDocument{\AtEndDocument{\par\vfil\penalty-10000\relax\the\pgfutil@everybye}}` to the document and this inserts the space.

In your example a work around is to add a \newpage before \end{document}. But if pgf puts something in the toks register `\pgfutil@everybye` this could lead to a second page.

Comment: It may not be `luatex`-specific in general, but at least for `adjustbox`, it is. The culprit seems to be the package `trimclip` loaded by `adjustbox`, which falls back to `pgf` if there is no file `tc-<driver>.def`. This happens for `luatex` because `trimclip` only provides `tc-{dvips,pdftex,pgf,xetex}.def`.

Comment: Yes, I know see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47085669#47085669. But any package that loads pgf would have a similar effect.

Comment: @Socob Fixed in next PGF release.  https://sourceforge.net/u/hmenke/pgf/ci/fbfabbd01cecb4e8b6b1e43d1f3ad685c7e60778/