# Extra space at the end of the document added by PGF

Tags: spacing, pgf-core, hooks

As seen in [this answer to my previous question “Extra vertical space at end of last column when loading adjustbox (only luatex)”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454395), loading the package `pgf` causes the following to be added at the end of the document (in `pgfutil-latex.def`):

```
\AtBeginDocument{\AtEndDocument{\par\vfil\penalty-10000\relax\the\pgfutil@everybye}}
```

As shown in the linked question, this can sometimes cause problems.

- Why is `pgf` doing this?
- If I don’t know whether `pgf` will be loaded in a given document, how can I get rid of this space? (Without having to modify the document content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As revealed in a [comment by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454379#comment1185822_454395), it seems that this issue should be addressed in a future PGF release:
https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/fbfabbd01cecb4e8b6b1e43d1f3ad685c7e60778/

I had also opened a bug report on the PGF/TikZ tracker: [#502 PGF can cause extra space at the end of a document (\pgfutil@everybye)](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/502/).

Answer (score 1):

As to why `pgf` is "doing this", it looks like a bug.

To deal with the faulty insertion of vertical space, you can try the following code just before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter    
\ifdefined\pgfutil@everybye \AtEndDocument{\clearpage\the\pgfutil@everybye}\else\relax\fi
\makeatother
```

The answer to [defining a fading-style directly in the fill command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51792/defining-a-fading-style-directly-in-the-fill-command) is informative, and I borrowed the `\AtEndDocument{...}` command from there.

Comment: How does this address what Ulrike wrote in the linked question? “In your example a work around is to add a `\newpage` before `\end{document}`. But if `pgf` puts something in the toks register `\pgfutil@everybye` this could lead to a second page.” Also, wouldn’t this output whatever is in `\pgfutil@everybye` twice?

Comment: I wasn't really trying to address what Ulrike wrote in the linked question. I was suggesting that you use the code above in the preamble so you don't need to modify the body of the document. The code above more or less checks whether pgf is loaded. I tested the above code with your document and it seems to prevent the unwanted space being inserted. I have looked into the meaning of `\pgfutil@everybye` and I think it's a bit beyond my understanding. I did wonder whether the `\AtEndDocument{...}` command could be "beaten" by an  `\AtVeryEnd` or something similar. Have you tested the code above?